# Python request download a file and save to a specific directory

Tags: django, python-3.x, csv, download, python-requests

Hello sorry if this question has been asked before.
But I have tried a lot of methods that provided.

Basically, I want to download the file from a website, which is I will show my coding below. The code works perfectly, but the problem is the file was auto download in our download folder path directory.

My concern is to **download the file and save it to a specific folder**.
I'm aware we can change our browser setting since this was a server that will remote by different users. So, it will automatically download to their temporarily **/users/adam_01/download/** folder.

I want it to save in server disk which is, **C://ExcelFile/**
Below are my script and some of the data have been changing because it is confidential.

```
import pandas as pd 
import html5lib 
import time from bs4 
import BeautifulSoup 
import requests 
import csv 
from datetime 
import datetime 
import urllib.request 
 import os

with requests.Session() as c:
    proxies = {"http": "http://:911"}

    url = 'https://......./login.jsp'
    USERNAME = 'mwirzonw'
    PASSWORD = 'Fiqr123'

    c.get(url,verify= False)
    csrftoken = ''



    login_data = dict(proxies,atl_token = csrftoken, os_username=USERNAME, os_password=PASSWORD, next='/')

    c.post(url, data=login_data, headers={"referer" : "https://.....com"})
    page = c.get('https://........s...../SearchRequest-96010.csv')

    location = 'C:/Users/..../Downloads/'

    with open('asdsad906010.csv', 'wb') as output:
        output.write(page.content )
    print("Done!")
```

Thank you, be pleased to ask if any confusing information was given.

Regards,
Fiqri

Answer (score 0):

It seems that from your script you are writing the file to `asdsad906010.csv`. You should be able to change the output directory as follows.

```
# Set the output directory to your desired location
output_directory = 'C:/ExcelFile/'

# Create a file path by joining the directory name with the desired file name
file_path = os.path.join(output_directory, 'asdsad906010.csv')

# Write the file
with open(file_path, 'wb') as output:
    output.write(page.content)
```